# How to pass data to an exact sibling component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have three sibling components which are populated using the same component as follows.

```
 <div *ngIf="unitLevel && tribeLevel && squadLevel">
      <at-unit-search [level]="unitLevel"></at-unit-search>
      <at-unit-search [level]="tribeLevel"></at-unit-search>
      <at-unit-search [level]="squadLevel"></at-unit-search>
 </div>
```

I need to pass some data from first sibling to third sibling, but not to second sibling.I used a service for this. But it sends data to all the three components.

**Unit search component's typescript**

```
export class UnitSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  operationalUnits: OperationalUnitLightWeight[];
  previousTimeAllSelected: boolean;
  @ViewChild('allSelected', { static: false }) private allSelected: MatOption;
  @Input() level: any;
  unitForm = new FormGroup({ unitControl: new FormControl('') });

  childUnits : any[];

  constructor(private commonServerService: CommonServerService,private sendUnitService: UnitService ) {
    this.childUnits=[];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.commonServerService.findOperationalUnitsByLevelId(this.level.id).subscribe(operationalUnits => {
      {
        this.operationalUnits = operationalUnits;
        this.operationalUnits.sort((a , b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
      }
    });

    this.sendUnitService.getArray().subscribe(units => {
     this.operationalUnits = units
    });

  }


  optionChange() {
    this.unitForm.controls.unitControl.value.forEach(id => {
      {
        if (id === 0) {
          this.previousTimeAllSelected = true;
        }
      }
    });
    let selectedUnitIds = this.toggleAllSelection();
    this.getChildUnits(selectedUnitIds);
  }

   getChildUnits(selectedUnitIds: any[]) {
    let children=  this.loadChildUnits(selectedUnitIds);
    this.sendUnitService.sendArray(children);
  }
```

This is happening because all three components are generated from same base component. Since every component has `getArray()` method which is called inside `ngOnInit()`, when data is sent from a particular component, all the three components are receiving that data.

Is there any way to uniquely send data to only the needed component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can first emit data to parent component then parent component will send that data to a specific component. Or you can use BehaviorSubject to publish and subscribe data.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can define a **global** variables in a **globle** service for this,

```
     //assuming that senUnitService is a global service.

     this.sendUnitService.unitLevel = unitLevel;
     this.sendUnitService.tribeLevel= tribeLevel;
     this.sendUnitService.squadLevel= squadLevel;

     //and if then in the sibling component 

     this.unitLevel = this.sendUnitService.unitLevel;
     this.tribeLevel = this.sendUnitService.tribeLevel;
     this.squadLevel = this.sendUnitService.squadLevel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

There're different possible solution but they depends on your needs.

If the the third child is "always" the only one interested to the notification, I'g to pass an Input.

```
<div *ngIf="unitLevel && tribeLevel && squadLevel">
      <at-unit-search [level]="unitLevel"></at-unit-search>
      <at-unit-search [level]="tribeLevel"></at-unit-search>
      <at-unit-search [level]="squadLevel" handleNotification="true"></at-unit-search>
</div>
```

and the in `ngOnInit`

```
if(this.handleNotification) {
    this.sendUnitService.getArray().subscribe(units => {
     this.operationalUnits = units
    });
}
```

if instead there's a way to filter the data emitted by `sendUnitService`, you could use

```
    this.sendUnitService.getArray().pipe(
       filter(x => .....),
       ....
     ).subscribe(units => {
       this.operationalUnits = units
     });
```

If both approach do not fit your needs I'd go to add some login in the service in order to allow component's instances to "register" to specific notifications.

PS. would be nice to have a minimal running example (I suggest to use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/))